# 'Does registration remain' or 'does registration remains'

Tags: verbs

I'm confused between these two sentences:

1. Till what time of the day does the registration **remain** open?
2. Till what time of the day does the registration **remains** open?

I understand that 'does' is always used with a singular noun. But my confusion is with the form of verb for 'remain'.

Please also explain your answer to prevent future conflict of the same sort.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145479/the-use-of-s-on-third-person-verbs-in-a-question-starting-with-does

Answer (score 1):

> Till what time of the day does the registration remain open?

The rule is very simple. With the auxiliary verb "do", the main verb always takes the **bare infinitive**.

There is never any exception to this rule.

*Do you remain?
Does he remain.
We did remain.*

Answer (score 0):

Here, the 's' is a conjugation of the verb as third person, present tense. The verb in the sentence is "does remain", a combination of an auxiliary verb and a main verb. You never duplicate the conjugation of a verb, so in your sentence, "remain" is the correct form.

If I may make a phrasing suggestion, "till what time of day" is not incorrect, but "how late" is more idiomatic.